# count people scheduled at work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with shift start and end times, with #N/A if the person is not due in at all.

(Sample)

```
Mon Start   Mon End
 8:15       16:45
 8:15       16:45
 8:15       16:45
11:30       20:00
 #N/A        #N/A
 8:15       16:45
 8:45       17:15
 9:30       18:00
13:30       22:00
```

I would like to know how many people are due to be on at a specified time
e.g. if i select 9:00 as the time, I would expect the result 5 from this query, and if I select 21:00, I would expect 1.

I have tried countif `=COUNTIF(A2:A93,"<"&D2)-COUNTIF(B2:B93,">="&D2)`, but that just produces negative numbers for the start of the day, and positive for the end of the day.

with sumproduct, `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A93>=D2),--(B2:B93<D2))`, I can only get `0` as the answer

Could someone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT won't ignore #N/A error values, if you have Excel 2007 or later try using COUNTIFS like this

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A93,"<="&D2,B2:B93,">="&D2)`

Comment: I appreciate you having included why sumproduct is problematic for this. Thanks